# Multi-step form | Form submit with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a multistep form. The page have 3 containers. When form on the first container is submitted, first container hides and second shows..

I want to move between between steps (container without page refreshing). The problem is when I send data with ajax and use event.preventDefault() or return false - data is not sending to my php page where I want to set input values from the form to sesssions. If i remove event.preventDefault then the data posts to the php page but it then also reloads the page and do no move to next "step"

This is how js looks like:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$('#myform').submit(function(event) {

event.preventDefault();

var formData = {
  '1': $('select[name=1]').val(),
  '2': $("#2").val(),
  '3': $('input[name=3]').val(),
  '4': $('input[name=4]').val(),
  '5': $('input[name=5]').val(),
  '6': $('input[name=6]').val(),
  '7': $('input[name=7]').val(),
};

$.ajax({
   type : 'POST',
   url : 'process.php', 
   data: formData,
})

$("#container1").css("display", "none");
$("#container2").css("display", "block");

});

});
```

Comment: if you're using ajax, you can sidestep using the submit event entirely. instead of using submit, you can set your button to type "button", and attach your ajax event to an on click listener.

Answer (score 0):

The submit event can be sidestepped to avoid all of this. Not sure what your html looks like, but if you have a button, you could do something like this, do your submit via ajax in a click event instead of a submit event:

```
<button class="submit-form-btn">Submit</button>
```

jQuery something like this:

```
$('.submit-form-btn').on('click', function () {
  $.ajax({
     type : 'POST',
     url : 'process.php', 
     data: formData
  })

  // do your css to show/hide next form
})
```

Comment: The button looks like this: <button id="nextStepButton" class="ui right labeled icon button"> Next </button> . If I put it inside form end press it, the form submits end reloads the page BUT if I put it outside form I get all css changes that I want BUT it doesn't send data to the php page

Comment: What I really need is to pass a value from an input on the first form (first step) to the next form (second step)